# Wireless connection on Ubuntu 16.04 takes multiple retries before successfull

Tags: wireless, network-manager, broadcom

I have Asus P8Z77-V motherborad with integrated WiFi adapter (BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n). 
Every time I want to connect to WiFi network it is taking really long time, like 2-3 minutes for each try. After the first attempt usually connection fails and I get up and down arrows instead of WiFi icon. If I try to connect again it sometimes (after waiting couple of minutes) connects, the other time connection fails again, and I have to repeat. I spend like 10 minutes every morning trying to connect to Wifi. 
After it finally connects if works normally, but if connection drops it is again very time consuming to reconnect.

**What can I do to diagnose this problem?** How to see if I have hardware of SW problem?

All other devices connect to same Wifi immediately so there is no problem with WiFi signal.

Situation is usually worse after waking up computer from sleep and usually if connects faster after fresh reboot. Sometimes I don't see list of wirelesss network and I have to do `sudo service network-manager restart` and after some time they appear again.

```
lshw -C network:

*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: 94:db:c9:9f:2f:ba
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7800000-f7803fff

rfkill list:

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
```